# How would I mock out Meteor.settings with jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, meteor, jestjs

Meteor.settings is being used in a react class component that I am trying to mock. In the constructor of that component, Meteor.settings is accessed to get a url.  I am using the moduleMapper from jest to mock Meteor.settings like so:

```
const Meteor = {
  settings: {
    public: {
      URL: "http://testing:0000",
    },
  },
};

export default Meteor;
```

In my test file I am importing my class component. After running jest, I am getting the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`.

To my understanding, the issue is that Meteor is not correctly being mocked.

How can I fix this issue, so that I can use a mock of Meteor.settings in my component?

Comment: we are having the same issue. Were you able to resolve this? Would help us a lot!

Comment: just answered this question. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mocking Meteor out in a separate file, I replaced each instance of Meteor with `(((Meteor || {}).settings || {}).public || {})`

For your case just include an empty dictionary w/ each level of the meteor dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I do this exact thing!

1. Include `meteor-jest-stubs` per the instructions in the [repo README.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-jest-stubs)
2. Stub out missing/custom pieces by including a file at `__mocks__/meteor/meteor.js` to mock the Meteor module.

```js
import { Meteor as MockedMongo } from "meteor/meteor"

export const Meteor = {
  ...MockedMongo,
  // then stub out any other meteor values, for example:
  absoluteUrl: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("http://localhost:3000/"),
  settings: {
    public: {
      URL: "http://testing:0000",
    },
    private: {
      MY_PRIVATE_KEY: "secret"
    }
  },
  subscribe: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    ready: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
    stop: jest.fn()
  })),
  // etc.
}
```

Then jest picks up on the `__mocks__` directory automatically and will mock out the Meteor value in your tests.
https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules